# Tridion New UI - Creating a Component Template

Tags: content-manager, sites-9.5, experience-space

Can someone advise in the new SDL UI experience space, Is it possible to create a Component Template or do you still have to use the old classic UI for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Tridion Sites 9.5 and 9.6 for the Component Template Creation in the new Experience Space UI are still not yet supported. yes for creating the new Component Template you need to switch to classic UI.

In case if you want to open the existing Component Template from the new UI which is possible it will open as the new window but still, it's Classic UI. but at least it's possible without switching to classic UI.

**For Tridion Sites 9.5:**

In the new UI Building Block folder, you should be able to create the following items.

- Folder
- Component
- Multimedia component
- Upload multimedia component

[image]

**For Tridion Sites 9.6:**

In the new UI Building Block folder, you should be able to create the following items.

- Folder
- Bundle
- Component
- Multimedia component
- Upload multimedia component

[image]

I hope it helps

Comment: Many thanks for your response.

Comment: @Jimos If the answer helped, please upvote and accept to close this ticket

Comment: Experience Space intentionally focused on daily editorial actions, which is why Components and Pages were introduced in the new UI, but not Templates. Sites 9.5 also introduced data (pipeline) publishing as well as the ability to create pages _without_ Component Templates, both to support headless publishing models. It might be Experience Space might not add a UI for Component Templates for a while or perhaps at all, depending on how headless approaches evolve. For comparison, we intentionally didn't add Content Manager-side (template render) preview in Experience Space. :-)